# Tradução Theme OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Eu estou para comprar um tema do OpenCart no ThemesForest, mas gostaria de saber se qualquer tema que comprar tenho opção de tradução. Tanto do site como do Painel.

1. É um pacote de tradução que baixo ou tenho que fazer isso direto no arquivo PHP  ?
2. Eu já tenho instalado o OpenCart com tema padrão. Se eu comprar outro, o painel administrativo será o do novo tema ou permanece o padrão ?
3. Qualquer tema que comprar tenho a opção de instalar plugins para frete, PagSeguro e outros ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- É um pacote sim. Na verdade quando eu instalei pt-br, baixei diretamente [daqui](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=13631), nesse link você tem as instruções de como instalar;

2 - Provavelmente será o mesmo, talvez ele tenha algum módulo adicional;

3 - Sim, qualquer plugin, pois o CMS sempre será o mesmo, o que você vai estar fazendo ao instalar algum tema é mudar a cara de sua loja, apenas.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Comment: Ajudou sim. Valeu.

Comment: De nada! Boa sorte, abraço.